# Why does change not get emitted when triggering click on b-form-checkbox?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils

Using Jest I'm trying to test that a method gets called when a toggle button is clicked. But before getting around to checking that the method is called, I want to check if `'change'` is emitted by the toggle button.

To do this I've tried to replicate the [`b-form-checkbox` test](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/a8a5d4efa340fe8ebdbf3a247e716e8ce3a4c2f1/src/components/form-checkbox/form-checkbox.spec.js#L1096) from the BootstrapVue repo. When I run the test, the component appears to be defined, but the test fails when checking for the emitted `'change'`:

```
expect(received).toBeDefined()

Received: undefined

 |
 |     await $input.trigger('click');
 |     expect(wrapper.emitted('change')).toBeDefined();
```

My `ToggleExample.vue` component file looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="filter-container">
    <b-form-checkbox switch size="lg" v-model="onlyActive" @change="onlyActiveChange()">
      Only active
    </b-form-checkbox>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'CheckboxExample',
  data() {
    return {
      onlyActive: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onlyActiveChange() {
      console.log('Only active checkbox changed!');
      this.$emit('onlyActiveChange', this.onlyActive);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

With the test file `ToggleExample.spec.js` as:

```
import {
  mount,
  createLocalVue,
} from '@vue/test-utils';

import { BootstrapVue } from 'bootstrap-vue';
import ToggleExample from 'ToggleExample.vue';

const localVue = createLocalVue();

localVue.use(BootstrapVue);

describe('ToggleExample.vue Render Test', () => {
  let wrapper = null;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(ToggleExample, {
      localVue,
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    wrapper.destroy();
  });

  it('toggle click emits change', async () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm).toBeDefined();
    expect(wrapper.emitted('change')).toBeUndefined();

    const $input = wrapper.find('.filter-container').find('input');
    expect($input).toBeDefined();

    await $input.trigger('click');
    // await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    expect(wrapper.emitted('change')).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

I've also tried, without success, adding the `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();` in case it was related to the DOM update cycle.